# SQl : find out count of last consecutive numbers from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

See above data.

For each student, I need to derive a count for the last consecutive days a student was present.

Can anyone please give me idea on this?

```
;with CTE As
(select 1 as stdId, 1 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 2 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 3 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 5 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 6 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 7 as dt
union
select 1 as stdId, 9 as dt
union
select 2 as stdId, 2 as dt
union
select 2 as stdId, 4 as dt
union
select 2 as stdId, 7 as dt
union
select 2 as stdId, 8 as dt
)
select stdId, dt
FROM 
CTE
```

---

Comment: Is the data oriented as you have it in excel image or as you've defined it in the CTE?

Comment: What does the CTE have to do with the data shown?  What results do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Classify the groups based on consecutive days present using the difference of dt and the rownumber.

2) Then get the last group for each student and the count for each group.

3) Finally select the count for last group per student.

```
select distinct stdid,cnt 
from (select stdid,grp,count(*) over(partition by stdid,grp) cnt,
      max(grp) over(partition by stdid) lastgrp
      from (select stdId, dt,dt-row_number() over(partition by stdid order by dt) grp
            FROM CTE) x
) y where lastgrp=grp
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/JLVSU85916)**

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a [recursive cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

This technique starts at the top and works its way down, by 1, until no more matches can be found.

```
;with CTE As
(
    select 1 as stdId, 1 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 2 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 3 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 5 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 6 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 7 as dt
        union
    select 1 as stdId, 9 as dt
        union
    select 2 as stdId, 2 as dt
        union
    select 2 as stdId, 4 as dt
        union
    select 2 as stdId, 7 as dt
        union
    select 2 as stdId, 8 as dt
),
CTEr AS 
(
    -- Use recursiion, starting at the top and working down by one.

        -- Anchor part.
        SELECT
            stdId,
            MAX(dt) AS dt
        FROM
            CTE
        GROUP BY 
            stdId

    UNION ALL

        -- Recursive part.
        SELECT
            r.stdId,
            r.dt -1 AS dt
        FROM
            CTEr AS r
                INNER JOIN CTE AS c     ON  c.stdId = r.stdId
                                        AND c.dt    = r.dt -1
)
select 
    stdId, 
    COUNT(dt) AS Result
FROM 
    CTEr
GROUP BY
    stdId
;
```

Performance can be a problem when using recursion, especially with larger datasets.  If this is the case I'd recommend using @vkp's approach.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want 1 for student 1 ("9") and is "2" for student 2 ("7" and "8") then:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stdid order by date) as seqnum
      from cte
      where student = @student
     ) t
order by (dt - seqnum) desc;
```

What does this do?  First, it generates a sequence number for each student.  The difference between this and the `dt` column is a constant for consecutive values of "dt".

Then, it simply orders by the difference and gets all rows with the highest difference.  These are the consecutive rows at the end.

This does make two assumptions:

- You want the sequence to be based on each student's highest value of `dt`, not on some overall highest value.
- There are no duplicates in the table.

These are reasonable assumptions based on the question and the data in the question.  There are pretty simple alternatives for handling other situations.

Finally, let me note that if your data looks more like the picture than the CTE, an easy way to transform it is:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from (select cte.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stdid order by date) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (values (t.[1]), (t.[2]), . . . ) v(dt)
      where student = @student and v.dt = 'yes'
     ) t
order by (dt - seqnum) desc;
```